# Map an object to another in Typescript

Tags: typescript, primeng, treenode

I have a role object that I wanted to map to a TreeNode object using PrimeNG to display it in a tree. 
The role object is something like this (shown in the picture as well)

```
role: [
id: ....
name: ....
   description: ....
   roles[]: .....
]
```

[image: role object]

The tree node object has the following structure is:

```
{
"data": 
[
    {
        "label": "Documents",
        "data": "Documents Folder",
        "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
        "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
        "children": [{
                "label": "Work",
                "data": "Work Folder",
                "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
                "children": [{"label": "Expenses.doc", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Expenses Document"}, {"label": "Resume.doc", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Resume Document"}]
            },
            {
                "label": "Home",
                "data": "Home Folder",
                "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
                "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
                "children": [{"label": "Invoices.txt", "icon": "fa-file-word-o", "data": "Invoices for this month"}]
            }]
    },
    {
        "label": "Pictures",
        "data": "Pictures Folder",
        "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
        "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
        "children": [
            {"label": "barcelona.jpg", "icon": "fa-file-image-o", "data": "Barcelona Photo"},
            {"label": "logo.jpg", "icon": "fa-file-image-o", "data": "PrimeFaces Logo"},
            {"label": "primeui.png", "icon": "fa-file-image-o", "data": "PrimeUI Logo"}]
    },
    {
        "label": "Movies",
        "data": "Movies Folder",
        "expandedIcon": "fa-folder-open",
        "collapsedIcon": "fa-folder",
        "children": [{
                "label": "Al Pacino",
                "data": "Pacino Movies",
                "children": [{"label": "Scarface", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Scarface Movie"}, {"label": "Serpico", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Serpico Movie"}]
            },
            {
                "label": "Robert De Niro",
                "data": "De Niro Movies",
                "children": [{"label": "Goodfellas", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Goodfellas Movie"}, {"label": "Untouchables", "icon": "fa-file-video-o", "data": "Untouchables Movie"}]
            }]
    }
]
```

}

```
 data.roles.forEach((role, index) => {
        //this.roleTree.label = role.Name;
        //this.roleTree.data = role.ID;

        let treeNode: TreeNode = {
            label: role.Name,
            data: role

        }

        this.treeNodes.push(treeNode);
        console.log(role);
        console.log(index);

    });
```

But this code seems to be too complex when I try 'roles' in 'role' to map to 'children' in treeNode. I have seen some examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934989/how-can-i-cast-an-object-with-fields-missing-to-another-in-typescript) but it is mapping the same field names.

I'm new to Typesript, is there a workaround to convert my role object with roles to treeNode with children by specifying my fieldname (e.g. name) to be mapped to 'label' of role?

A code example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an `interface` for your role type or the `TreeNode` type?  Does `TreeNode` allow an arbitrary object for its `data` property, and is its `children` an array of `TreeNode`s?

Comment: and what is the type of the elements of the `roles` property?  Are they the same type as the `role` object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, I'm not 100% sure about the `Role` and `TreeNode` types you're using.  Here's my guess based on the code in your question.

`Role` has a few properties you care about, but the tricky one is the `roles` property, which I am guessing is meant to be an array of `Role` objects:

```
interface Role {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  roles: Role[];
}
```

Likewise, `TreeNode` has some properties, but the tricky one is the `children` property which is an array of `TreeNode` objects.  Also, I'm assuming that `TreeNode` is generic in the type of `data`, and in this case you want to do `TreeNode<Role>`, meaning the `data` property will be a `Role` object:

```
interface TreeNode<T> {
  label: string;
  data: T;
  expandedIcon?: string;
  collapsedIcon?: string;
  children: TreeNode<T>[];
}
```

*If* those are correct, then you can use the following `roleToTreeNode()` function to map a `Role` object to a `TreeNode<Role>` object:

```
function roleToTreeNode(role: Role): TreeNode<Role> {
  return {
    label: role.name,
    data: role,
    children: role.roles.map(roleToTreeNode)
  };
}
```

The `children:` line is the operative part of the function: you are taking the `role.roles` array, and mapping each `Role` element to a `TreeNode<Role>`, which is what the `roleToTreeNode()` function does.  That is, `roleToTreeNode()` is a recursive function which calls itself.

Does this make sense?  Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Looks good, but let me give it a try and will get back to you.

Comment: This works like a charm thanks alot. But i have another question. Could you explain how roleToTreeNode works? I have a lot of Children within Children Arrays how does it map everything to 1 Element?

Comment: It's [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#In_computer_science).  The body of `roleToTreeNode()` creates an object literal whose `children` property is assembled by calling `roleToTreeNode` on each element of `role.roles`.  You could do it iteratively with a `for` loop instead of using the `map()` array method, but it's the same thing.  Recursion.

Comment: @jcalz here is my input response expecting the same output as in the question. `[{
        "$id": "1",
        "cityId": 2,
        "cityName": "India",
        "Description": "India",
        "parentId": 0,
        "cities": [{
  
     "$id": "2",
     "cityId": 3,
     "cityName": "delhi",
     "Description": "delhi",
     "parentId": 1,
     "cities": [
       {child},
       {child}
     ]
    }
   ]
}]`

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029918/angular-primeng-treenode-convert-class-into-treenode-cannot-read-property-map) the following link helped me getting the recursion done and able to get my response