# Angular PrimeNg TreeNode : convert class into TreeNode, cannot read property map of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster, primeng, treenode

I'm working on an application generated by JHipster and using Angular 4.3. 
I'm trying to use the [tree component of PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree)

I'm trying to convert an array of objects into an array of TreeNode, in order to be displayed like a tree.

My typescript model looks like this :

```
export class Continent implements BaseEntity {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public name?: string,
        public countries?: Country[]
) { }
```

I've followed [this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991866/map-an-object-to-another-in-typescript) which describes how to convert interfaces (but in my case I have classes) and I've thoses functions (where there is the error):

```
private continentsToTreeNodes(continents: Continent[]) {
    for (let cont of continents) {
        this.continentsNodes.push(this.continentToTreeNode(cont));
    }
}

private continentToTreeNode(cont: Continent): TreeNode {
    return {
        label: cont.name,
        data: cont,
        children: cont.countries.map(this.continentToTreeNode) // error at this line : cannot read property map of undefined
    };
}
```

Those functions are executed at the initialization of my component :

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

continents: Continent[];
continentsNodes: TreeNode[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadAll();
    }

    loadAll() {
        this.continentService.query().subscribe(
            (res: ResponseWrapper) => {
                this.continents = res.json;
                this.continentsToTreeNodes(this.continents);
            },
            (res: ResponseWrapper) => this.onError(res.json)
        );
    }

}
```

My JSON looks like this :

```
[{
"id": 1,
"name": "Africa",
"countries": [{
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Cameroon",
        "continentId": 1
        }, {
        ... // other countries
],{
// other continents
...
```

Does anyone know why I have this error message with my countries ?

**EDIT :** 
I've put logs in continentToTreeNode, and I can see that it's the recursive function the problem. 
At the first loop I have all the countries of the first Continent, and it crashed at the second loop, the attribute cont.countries is undefined.

How is it possible and how can I fix it ? In my JSON I have all the countries of each continent...

Comment: cont.countries is empty, I can't see the whole json input, but it is not complete. Try log out cont in continentToTreeNode to see which one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved my (stupid) problem, I was iterating on an function which requires continents, and I was trying to convert countries. It's ok with another functions which transform the countries :

```
private continentsToTreeNodes(continents: Continent[]) {
    for (let cont of continents) {
        this.continentsNodes.push(this.continentToTreeNode(cont));
    }
}

private continentToTreeNode(cont: Continent): TreeNode {
    let countiesTreeNodes: TreeNode[] = [];

    if (cont.countries !== undefined) {
        for (let c of cont.countries) {
            countriesTreeNodes.push(this.paysToTreeNode(c));
        }
    }
    return {
        label: cont.nom,
        data: cont,
        children: countriesTreeNodes
    };
}

private countryToTreeNode(country: Country) : TreeNode {
    return {
        label: country.nom,
        data: country
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much it solved my issue too. by the way how did you manage to incorporate the syling and scroll sort funtionality